# Node.js Promises - accessing scoped variable in then()

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, promise

*Node version: 8.1.3*

Hey guys,

I will try to make this as simple as possible =)

I have a daily .xlsx report with stats fetched from an API. it was working smoothly. However, at some point I had to move from *Promise.all* to resolving Promises in a sequence fashion, given the fact that API was throwing a considerable number of "Under heavy load" errors when all calls were made in parallel and I did not want to program any concurrency functions for that.

So far so good.

*First problem* -> for one part of the data API does not return me exactly what I want. I need Stats aggregated by, let´s call *type* and *day*. However, API can´t aggregate both at the same time, so I have to go on a loop and request the *type* aggreg. for each day I need.

*Second problem* -> API won´t return in the JSON which day the request was made for, so I have assign it to the object in the then() statement

```
for (var date = moment(startDate); date.isBefore(yesterday); date.add(1, 'days')) {
    promiseStats.push((() => {
        var report = rep;
        var requestDate = date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        return getStats(adv.id, {
            dayFrom: date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            dayTo: date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            groupBy: 'campaign'
        }).then((res) => {
            _.each(res, (o) => {
                Object.assign(o, {
                    day: requestDate
                })
            });
            report.data.push(...res);
        }); // getCampaignStats()
    })); // end promiseStats.push
} // for date end
```

I created an anonymous function to scope the variable and be able to access it when resolving the Promise. This was working nicely when I was using *Promise.all* . However, when I changed the code to resolve in sequence, it, of course, stopped working, since code only run that anonymous function when the promise will be resolved and by then, ***date*** is not the same value.

This is how I´m resolving promises now:

```
promiseStats.reduce((p, fn, index) => {
    return p.then(val => {
        return fn();
    });
}, Promise.resolve()).then(() => { 
 //do stuff here
});
```

***Question*** Is there a way to go around this and have the correct date value assigned to the object? This has been a stumbling block for me for some days already. I think I could solve this by going back to old code and use concurrency and balance the number of calls to avoid overloading API.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This would only work if you create copy of date, for each iteration stop of the loop.

Comment: Return the date in the first `then()` so it is available in the next one

Comment: Solution 1: Put the dates in the array, not the closures. Solution 2: just use `let` instead of `var` for the loop variable

Comment: @Bergi `let` won't work in that case, because `date` itself changes with each iteration, and no copy is created. So I would not say it is an exact duplicate, because the linked question is about primitives, but this question is about an object that changes in each iteration.

Comment: @t.niese Oh, you're right. One needs to create new date values for each iteration (in both solutions) anyway. I guess `date = moment(date)` could be used to copy them

Comment: @Bergi yes I think `let` and `date=moment(date.add(1, 'days'))` would work.

Comment: thanks for the replies here! @Bergi and t.niese , do you say that in for loop the date should be declared with let? 'for( let date = moment(startDate);...)'.

Comment: hmm it actually worked `for (let date = moment(startDate); date.isBefore(yesterday); date=moment(date.add(1, 'days')))` =). Dates are now +1, but this I can figure out why is happening. Thanks for the help here!

Comment: @skullmetal the purpose of `let` is explained in the duplicate. the `moment(date.add(1, 'days'))`  ensures that a copy of the date is assigned to the `date` variable, so that the you can make use of `let` functionality.